# Embed local mp4 video into MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html5-video

I am trying to embed a local mp4 file that resides on the same server where IIS runs but on a different disk and is not part of the site (too many videos to do that). For example, my site is under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Site while mp4 files I'd like to play are under D:\Videos. User running the site has access to this location. When I put full path to the file in the source, video does not play. What is the best way to handle this?

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
    <source src="D:/Videos/VideoFile.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: make sure browser supports video tag as it is a html5 tag..

Comment: I am using Chrome so I think that is covered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right to do that, you need virtual path and not a physical one just put mp4 file inside your project directory and then specify path as...

```
Try using 'http://[Your server]/directory/yourmp4.mp4' or use Server.MapPath() as src of your object.
```

and make sure your browser supports `video` tag as it is a `html5` tag.

Comment: I know that will work but since I have 2 TB worth of video files, including them all in my project is not an option.

Comment: @Mensur.. well then in that case ..may be this link will help you..   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150